# How to loop data from multiple tables in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I have these tables with the following columns:

**Article**

```
1.1. title
1.2. text
1.3. sortnr
```

**Congress**

```
2.1. title
2.2. text
2.3. sortnr
```

And, obviously, others, but these are the ones that are the same. And what I'd like to do is write a query where I can then loop through these fields as if they were from one table.

What it looks like:

`SELECT * FROM article, congress ORDER BY sortDate DESC LIMIT 3`

but with that I can't use fields like `title` and so on because during the loop, all the, for example, `title` fields are being turned in to the ones from `congress` table.

Is there a way to mix the two tables and treat them like they were from one table considering that they aren't joined in any way?

Comment: Lookup `JOIN` syntax in my sql. [update] did not see the same column names, better do it like my next comments

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions already did, which join would you suggest?

Comment: `SELECT a.title as atitle , b.title as btitle FROM article a, konferansenentry b`

Comment: `SELECT *` is bad practise. try to not use it.

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions yes, but then when looping the title, I'd have to use atitle and btitle, but I want to use just title so that the php part doesn't get affected.

Comment: Mmmh, then do 2 querys and not try to do it with one. Why overcomplicate things. Rest can be done in php.

Comment: is "konferansenentry" the same as "Congress" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT *, 'article' as tblnm FROM article
UNION
SELECT *, 'konferansenentry' as tblnm FROM konferansenentry 
ORDER BY sortDate DESC 
LIMIT 3
```

It will only work if both table have same field other wise you have to select individual one by one.

Comment: Thank you very much, works like a charm :) will accept in 9min

Comment: Nice solution. Thump up.

Comment: Glad it worked. You can also visit : Ask questions, get answers, no distractions to get more information about SO and support me as much as you can.